# How to solve $\int^1_{-1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> I have to solve $$\int^1_{-1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

I am a Calculus 1 student, and I am having difficulty because I can't think of anything that I could make into a substitute which would cancel much. I think this may be a difficult problem to solve without using techniques that are beyond a college Calculus 1 level of skill, but please try, or I may have a hard time understanding what you mean.

Here is some of what I've tried:

$u=1+x^2$

$du = 2xdx$

$\frac{du}{2x} = dx$

$$\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{u} \cdot \sin(x) \cdot \frac{1}{2x} \cdot du$$

I have tried plugging this into [Symbolab.com,](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bsin%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx) but it wont even give me a hint what $u$ should be.

Comment: Beyond the problem, take a look at [Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules). These are rules that allow us to reduce ourselves to integrate a rational fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ you do not need any substitution at all. What do you know about an integral with symmetric boundaries of an odd function?

---

For a given odd function $f(x)$, i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$, integrated over a symmetric interval $[-a,a]$, note that we get the following by enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto -x$

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm dx&=\int_a^{-a}f(-x)(-1)\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{-a}^af(-x)\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm dx\\
\therefore~2\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm dx&=0\\
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm dx~=~0$$

Now consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}$. Is this one odd; if so what is the integral over the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I don't know what a symmetric integral is.

Comment: @LuminousNutria Something of the form $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm dx$$ Maybe it would be better to call it an integral with symmetric boundaries.

Comment: Oh, so basically, an interval where in the range $[a,b]$ where $|a|=b$ or $|b|=a$?

Comment: @LuminousNutria Yes; more or less `^^'` I would call an interval of the form $[-a,a]$ or $[-b,b]$, respectively, symmetric where on the other hand something like $[a,a]$ doesn't really belong to this kind. Do you know how to reduce the integral $$\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm dx$$ where $f(x)$ is an odd function, i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is there a term for that I could google? Symmetric Interval?

Comment: @LuminousNutria It's a fundamental property of integrals of odd functions! However, it's quite simple too. See my edit :) And see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Basic_calculus_properties) for instance.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: @LuminousNutria Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 5):

Since, $\frac{\sin(-x)}{1+(-x)^2}=-\frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$ the function is symmetric over the interval of $[-1,1]$. Therefore we can evaluate the integral as:

> $$\int^1_{-1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=0$$

Here is a visual representation of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try $u = -x$. You may get something very similar but different. Actually, this substitution will give $I = -I$, if $I$ is the original integral.
You can solve that integral when the integration interval is given as $[-a, a]$.

Comment: Different to what?

Comment: @LuminousNutria Original integral.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is an *odd* function. Odd functions have the property the $f(-x)=-f(x)$. You do not need to find an actual antiderivative to solve this problem, since the integrand on $[-a,0)$ is the negative of the function on $(0,a]$. Therefore, the answer is zero.

Comment: If this function is $f(x)$ then are you saying $F(x)-F(-x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is odd.

Comment: Try it with other odd functions, like $\sin(x)$, or $x^3$.